# SQL*Loader-522: lfiopn failed

Tags: unix, sql-loader

I am getting this error when trying to run a shell script to run a control file, via remoting into a unix development environment. The error is

SQL*Loader-522: lfiopn failed for file (/xxx/xxx/xxx/logs/sql/xxxx.log)

After researching this issue it appears that for most people this is a permissions issue, but I checked my permissions on this directory and here is what I have :drwxrwxrwx, so all levels have full access from what I understand about permissions in Unix. I even tried to create a log file in the directory by typing touch test.log which created that file successfully.

Is there any other reason I would be getting this error? All of the research I've done on this always points to a permissions issue however I have been told by the security department that they verified I have the same permissions as my co-worker who can run this script fine. Any advice would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with this, this ended up being a permission issue as well, but in a different way. I have permissions on the folder but do not have permissions to write over the log file that's already in existence as another user in my group had created it last time it was ran. In order to run it successfully, I had to delete the log file entirely before I could run it. We share the same permissions however neither of us have permissions to overwrite each others files without deleting them first.